# Visual Studio 2014 Scaffolding AspNetUser table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I want to edit user information in AspNetUser table by using Scaffolding.  When I added scaffolded item from AspNetUser table, a controller and views are created. However, I cannot access the any views, but I only get an error, "The resource cannot be found."

Is there any way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

With out code if tough for provide solution, but here are few possible solutions

- Check if View Name is same as in action method.
- Check if model class referenced in Views are having correct path.

To check second thing, Open your Model class Cs page and compare the path there to Path mentioned in View .